# Ignoring JSON Schemas in SinkConnectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema

We currently use a ElasticsearchSinkConnector within our kafka-connect-cluster to move data from Kafka to Elastic. We utilize JSON-Schemas and the SchemaRegistry in our setup.

In this use-case our data is very dynamic and thus can only be defined as a `type: object` in our JSON-Schema. When sending the following message,

```
{
   data: {
      propOne: "hi"
      propTwo: "hi"
   },
   type: "Person",
}
```

with the following schema,

```
{
   required: ["data", "type"],
   properties: {
      "type": { type: "String" }
      "data": { type: "Object" }
   },
}
```

we run into the following problem:

Our ElasticSinkConnector *only* gets a *connect-struct* that contains a `type` with the corresponding string-value, but always an empty `data`-object. This makes sense, as based on the schema, this is the maximum structure it can infer. However, we would of course like to move the whole original `data`-object to our elasticsearch instance and not only an empty object.

That's the basic flow:
[image]

The Elasticsearch Sink Connector supports JSON (schemaless) data output from Apache Kafka topics. But if we use the `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` converter to ignore the schema we, of course, get the issue, that the *subjectid*-byte cannot be interpreted. Thus I'm looking for something like `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` that ignores the *subjectid* and *magicbyte*, takes the JSON however it comes and dumps it into elastic.

*Alternatives we are aware of: we could of course use a schemaless JSON-event for this use-case/topic. We still would like to avoid this, as our producer does currently not support it.*

Comment: What happens if you set `schema.ignore=true` in the connector config?

Comment: Hi Robin, unfortunately, nothing changes, as I think that `schema.ignore` just ignores the connector-struct-schema when writing to elastic. But the problem is IMHO already a step before, as the data never lands in the connect-struct after value-conversion.